# OpenCV createsamples - invalid background description file

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, sample, training-data

I'm in my `OPENCV_ROOT` folder and running the following command in Win-x64:

```
opencv_createsamples -bgcolor 0 -bgthresh 0 -maxxangle 1.1 -maxyangle 1.1 
maxzangle 0.5 -maxidev 40 -w 80 -h 40 
-img ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_POSITIVE_IMAGES_FOLDER\car.jpg 
-bg ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_PROJECT\negatives.txt
-vec ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_SAMPLES_FOLDER\car.jpg.vec 
-num 125
```

My `negatives.txt` looks like this:

```
negative_images\city01_02.jpg
negative_images\city01_04.jpg
negative_images\city01_05.jpg
negative_images\city01_06.jpg
negative_images\city01_07.jpg
```

This is my output:

```
Info file name: (NULL)
Img file name: ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_POSITIVE_IMAGES_FOLDER\car.jpg
Vec file name: ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_SAMPLES_FOLDER\car.jpg.vec
BG  file name: ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_PROJECT\negatives.txt
Num: 125
BG color: 0
BG threshold: 0
Invert: FALSE
Max intensity deviation: 40
Max x angle: 1.1
Max y angle: 1.1
Max z angle: 0.5
Show samples: FALSE
Width: 80
Height: 40
Create training samples from single image applying distortions...
Invalid background description file.
```

What's invalid about my negatives collection file (`negatives.txt`)? I tried listing the files within it both with absolute paths and with relative paths. I'm following [this](http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html) tutorial.

Comment: This is a tough problem. Hmm. Have you tried naming the full path inside the negatives.txt? For instance, `C:\images\negative_images\city01_02.jpg` instead of just `negative_images\city01_02.jpg`?

Comment: Another reason I suspect could be the `_` in the image name.

Comment: Yes, I've tried without underscores, it didn't make a difference. I also tried using full paths in negatives. I even copied the negative_images folder into the folder with the opencv_createsamples binary too, but no difference.

Comment: I've managed to make it work! The problem was simply that I had written the collection file names in Notepad++, and it all seemed fine. But when I happened to open the same file in notepad, I noticed there were no newlines after each image filename! When I added the newlines, I was able to make samples! However, it seems the negatives somehow aren't showing up. When I view the samples, they're distorted as expected, but on a black background, instead on a background using one of the negative images... Any idea?

Comment: Hey, I had a different solution. Basically created an empty bg2.txt file and paste all the bg.txt file content. See it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37378638/opencv-invalid-background-description-file/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved! The issue was simply that I had written the collection file names in Notepad++, and it all seemed fine. But when I happened to open the same file in notepad, I noticed there were no newlines after each image filename! When I added the newlines, and ran the command, the samples got created without errors!

Answer (score 5):

If you created the file on Windows, and running it on Linux e.g. Ubuntu, you have to change the "End of line sequence".

Click on the bottom of the editor on CR LF and change it to **LF** and try again!

Notepad++:

[image: Notepad++ image:]

Visual Studio Code:

[image: Visual Studio Code image:]

Geany: Documents > Set Line Endings > Convert and Set to LF (Unix)

[image: Geany image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Just skip **lines** between addresses of the images. For example: before my **negatives.dat** file was:

```
./Negative_Images/197.
./Negative_Images/69.
./Negative_Images/510.
./Negative_Images/513.
./Negative_Images/169.png
```

Now it's:

```
./Negative_Images/197.png



./Negative_Images/69.png



./Negative_Images/510.png



./Negative_Images/513.png



./Negative_Images/169.png
```

Problem solved.

Comment: This is exactly the suggestion of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was creating this `bg.txt` file with a script. Basically, it was doing :

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfImages; i++)
    {
                myDescFile << imagesFolder + std::to_string(i) + ".jpg\n";
    }
```

I simply added another `\n` and the problem went away!

`myDescFile << imagesFolder + std::to_string(i) + ".jpg\n\n";`

**EDIT:**

**You also have to make sure that your paths have**`/`or`\\` as separators. Else, you will be able to run the `opencv_createsamples.exe` cmd, won't have error, but **will never see** the `Done` at the end.

ex:`L:/imgTraining/plant/bnw/0.jpg`

Here's a picture of a good bg file from notepad++ (With `View>Show Symbol>Show End of Line` activated and `Edit>EOL Conversion>Windows (CR LF)` selected):

[image]

Comment: I tried all of the above. The strange thing is: opencv_createsamples.exe (v. 3.4.7) runs through a couple of 100 files and then gives me that error. If I delete that specific line from my bg.txt it runs past it, but stops at another line with the same error. I repeated this ca. 20 times, but everytime it stops at another one. 
e.g. /neg/IMG_3049.JPG would process but next line /neg/IMG_3051.JPG would fail.

Answer (score 0):

Install `dos2unix` on Linux by `sudo apt-get install dos2unix`.
And now you just need to use `dos2unix YourFileName.txt`.